# Inheritance concrete class json

Tags: java, json

I have a concrete java class Animal and its subclass's Dog, Cat etc.
When sending a json request I want to send all common fields in Animal once and then fields specific to Dog and Cat. Something like

```
{
    "Animal": {
        "A": "aa",  
        "B":"bb",
        "C":"cc",
        [
            "dog": {
                "D": "dd",
                "E": "ee"
            }

            "cat": {
                "F": "ff",
                "G": "gg"
            }
        ]
}
}
```

The idea is not to have repeat the fields of my concrete class with each subclass.

How to write serializer/deserializer for this. I am using jackson, spring and java.

I know about using some annotation like these:

```
`@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
property = "type",
visible = false)
@JsonSubTypes(@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"))`
```

But that do not work for the structure i am looking for

Comment: What's the benefit that you get from complicating your data structure in this way?

Comment: Do you really need to do that? Is your JSON so big that you need that optimisation? If not I would suggest to not do that.

Comment: I have classes with lots of fields in base class as well as subclass, I dont want to repeat it with each subclass fields.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that with annotations alone, you might need to write code to identify all the common values for all the fields for all the animals.